# JWT Token Refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt

Hello I am using JWT for authentication in my laravel 5 application.  The application currently resides on a live server and has several APIs that other apps can connect to.

Currently I am building a mobile app that connects to some of these APIs, as you know with mobile apps when the user logs in once I want them to remain logged in for a very long time.

To do this I found out that I need to refresh the JWT when it's a expired, apparently this will generate a new token and blacklist the old one.

I use that latest version of [Tymon/JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) which includes a new 
`blacklist_grace_period` feature.  This allows me to set a delay for when the token is refreshed and the old one is blacklisted.

My question now is, having the following in my route file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.website'.(App::environment('production') ? '.com' : '.dev'), 'prefix' => '/api/v1/manager/', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\BackEnd\Controllers', 'middleware' => ['before' => 'jwt.auth', 'after' => 'jwt.refresh', 'acl'], 'is' => 'manager'], function() {
    /** Manager Resource Routes */
    Route::resource('events', 'EventManagerController');
});
```

How do I then get the newly generated token and return to the client after a `jwt.refresh`? Or is that automatically appended to the response of the request?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the after-middleware that you are using:

vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Middleware/RefreshToken.php

First it parses the token, then refreshes it:

```
try {
    $newToken = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->parseToken()->refresh();
}
```

Then it adds it to the response's header:

```
$response->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$newToken);

return $response;
```

So, yes, this is indeed where the newly refreshed token is added to the response.